# Integration of Glassfish with JDeveloper

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, jdeveloper

Is there any way that i can integrate a Glassfish application server inside my JDeveloper 11.1.1.4.0 installation and deploy applications directly from my IDE to the Glassfish server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace the integrated WLS with Glassfish but you can use Ant tasks to do the deployment to glassfish and then add menu items to start/stop Glassfish.
Here is an example with Tomcat:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/tomcat_extensions_for_jdevelop_1

Comment: I've used that before that about Tomcat. Never thought about it could work also on glassfish. Thanks