# Deploy .war developed in jdeveloper on glassfish4.0

Tags: web-services, deployment, glassfish, jdeveloper

I developed a .war file in jdeveloper 10.1.3. And I want to deploy it on glassfish4.0 server which is standalone server.

Firstly I write a java code as

```
package com.oi.testdemohello;

public class TestHello {
    public TestHello() {
    }

    public String sayHello(String name){
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
```

Than I create a J2EE1.4(JAX-RPC) and SOAP 1.1 Binding web services from that code in jdeveloper which statefull service.

The WSDL generated is as :

```
<definitions
     name="MyWebService"
     targetNamespace="http://testdemohello.oi.com/"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:tns="http://testdemohello.oi.com/"
     xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
     xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
     xmlns:tns0="http://testdemohello.oi.com/types/"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://testdemohello.oi.com/types/"
         elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:tns="http://testdemohello.oi.com/types/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:soap11-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

        <element name="sayHelloElement">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="name" type="string" nillable="true"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="sayHelloResponseElement">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="result" type="string" nillable="true"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
</types>
<message name="MyWebService_sayHello">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns0:sayHelloElement"/>
</message>
<message name="MyWebService_sayHelloResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns0:sayHelloResponseElement"/>
</message>
<portType name="MyWebService">
    <operation name="sayHello">
        <input message="tns:MyWebService_sayHello"/>
        <output message="tns:MyWebService_sayHelloResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="MyWebServiceSoapHttp" type="tns:MyWebService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="sayHello">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://testdemohello.oi.com//sayHello"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="MyWebService">
    <port name="MyWebServiceSoapHttpPort" binding="tns:MyWebServiceSoapHttp">
        <soap:address location="http://localMachine3:8888/TestDemoHello-DemoHello-context-root/MyWebServiceSoapHttpPort"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Than I deploy a .war file of this.

Now I want to deploy this .war file to glassfish 4.0 server. But I am not able to do it. How to do it please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different options, outlined for example in this question: [Best way to deploy on Glassfish V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635861/best-way-to-deploy-on-glassfish-v3). Your easiest option is to use the Glassfish Admin GUI on `http://localhost:4848`.

If you want something that is integrated in JDeveloper you can try [GlassFish Extension for Oracle JDeveloper](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/glassfish_extension_for_oracle_jdeveloper) or read [this article](http://www.thinkquest.org/competition/application_development/jdeveloper.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793812/integration-of-glassfish-with-jdeveloper).